# What is the difference between Service and Helper in sails.js?

Tags: sails.js

On sails.js official [documentation on services](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/services) it says "Although Services are still fully supported in Sails 1.0, it is recommended that you use helpers instead.".

When should I use service vs helper? What is the core difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

A service is a singleton instance which is present all the time. There is just one single instance for all calls. You could use this if you want to let mutiple requests or sockets communicate with each other.

A helper is like a function. Every call of it is independent from others.
(As long as you don't use global variables)

If you are using services, you should be very careful because the same instance is called by different users.

Comment: Can you provide some references?